# How to dettach input devices in startup?

Tags: boot, usb, startup, udev, xinput

I would like to dettach external input devices connected to the computer on boot (external mouse, keyboard, badusb). Udev cannot help me with that because the input devices are connected in boot time.

I have tried to create a script via rc.local and xinput, however it seems like xinput is unknown in startup (when I run to script manually, it worked, so its a xinput and boot problem).

Are there other ways to do so in startup without blocking an entire usb port?

Comment: Is there a reason to do this? Give us more information please.

Comment: Yea, im trying to enforce udev rules on pre boot connected device. In order to do so, I have to create an insertion event of the device after the boot (I force the user to reconnect the device after boot). It works with usb devices as I disconnect them via udiskctl, but could not find solution for hid.

Answer (score -1):

you can use (xinput):

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. HP Wireless Keyboard and Mouse id=10 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0707:00 04F3:30DA Touchpad           id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2514:00 04F3:23C4                   id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2514:00 04F3:23C4 Pen               id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                   id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard             id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                               id=7 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. HP Wireless Keyboard and Mouse id=9 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi         id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                         id=15 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                 id=16 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=17 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                           id=18 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                     id=19 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: The user is aware of xinput. So do you want to give more details about how to do what you're suggesting?

Comment: As I said, xinput is unknown in rc.local so it won't work